# Pandas appending across columns (or SQL)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe where `-` and `$` is data

```
A B C 01/01/18 01/08/18
- - -     $        $
- - -     $        $
- - -     $        $
```

I would like to transform into the following

```
A B C  Period   Cost
- - -  01/01/18 $
- - -  01/01/18 $
- - -  01/01/18 $
- - -  01/08/18 $
- - -  01/08/18 $
- - -  01/08/18 $
```

I know I can create two dataframes for each period `df1 and df2` then `total = df2.append(df1)` but I would have to create 52 dataframes for the year. Is there an easier way to do this using some fancy transpose?

### Updated Approach

I am trying to do the following `df.grouby(['A','B',C'])` but I need to `df.transpose()` first I believe. If someone can help me out with this approach even if its in SQL I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's what [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) does:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'], var_name='Period', value_name='Cost')

#   A  B  C    Period Cost
#0  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#1  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#2  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#3  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
#4  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
#5  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
```

You can also set unchanged columns as index and then `stack` the other columns:

```
ids = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df.set_index(ids).stack().rename_axis(ids + ['Period']).rename('Cost').reset_index()

#   A  B  C    Period Cost
#0  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#1  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
#2  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#3  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
#4  -  -  -  01/01/18    $
#5  -  -  -  01/08/18    $
```

Comment: No way dude `pandas.melt` ??? how do you even know this lol. Thank you so much. I am trying my own approach if you can take a look at my edit above.